# Can't get lodash-es import module workin with my jest test

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, remix

Hello I can't get my lodash-es module working with my jest test I Always get this error:
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

This is my current configuration in my remix app:

jest.config.js

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
 module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
       "/node_modules/(?!(lodash-es)/)"
    ]
 };
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }], 
    '@babel/preset-typescript']
};
```

[image: error log]

Comment: I had to change the imports to using member imports using the {} instead of default import.

Second, I had to add this line extra line in my jest.config:

  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  },